# $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_Xf^nd\mu$ is finite then $\mu(\{x|f \gt 1\})=0$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $(X,\mu$) be measure space with finite measure i.e. $\mu(X)<\infty$ and $f:X\to [0,+\infty]$ is measurable function. Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_Xf^nd\mu$ is finite then $\mu(\{x|f \gt 1\})=0$.

Let's assume that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_Xf^nd\mu=a\lt\infty$  and that $\mu(\{x|f \gt 1\})\gt0$.

I can write $\int_Xf^nd\mu$ as $\int_Xf^nd\mu=\int_{X_{1}}f^nd\mu + \int_{X_{2}}f^nd\mu + \int_{X_{3}}f^nd\mu$ where $X_1=\{x|0\leq f<1\}$, $X_2=\{x|f=1\}$ and $X_3=\{x|f>1\}$

We have that $\int_{X_{2}}f^nd\mu + \int_{X_{3}}f^nd\mu=\int_{X_{2}}1d\mu + \int_{X_{3}}f^nd\mu=\mu(X_2)+\int_{X_{3}}f^nd\mu\leq\int_Xf^nd\mu$ 
Since at $X_3$, $f>1$ then $f^n<f^{n+1}$ so by Monotone convergence we have that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{X_{3}}f^nd\mu=\int_{X_{3}}\lim_{n\to \infty}f^nd\mu=\int_{X_{3}}\infty d\mu=\infty\mu(X_3)=\infty$. Then it follows $\lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(X_2)+\int_{X_{3}}f^nd\mu=\infty\leq a$ which is a contradiction. Hence $\mu(\{x|f \gt 1\})=0$.

Comment: I've seen that there are similar questions posted, but i need this proof checked.